# Using Reactjs to align and display results based on Contestant ID

Tags: reactjs

The code below displays three Election Contestants from the arrays.

Now I want to show their vote counts for each contestanst based on their Ids.

here is the arrays showing various contestant results that i want to merge based on their Id's

```
contestantResult: [
  { id: 1, voteCount: "500 Votes" },
  { id: 2, voteCount: "200 Votes" },
  { id: 3, voteCount: "320 votes" },
],
```

My issues is stated below:

Each time I run the code, all the three contestant are seen having 500 votes but in reality based on their Ids,

**Contestant 1 should have 500 votes.**

**Contestant 2 should have 200 votes.**

**Contestant 3 should have 320 votes.**

I guess I have to loop through the contestant Vote results arrays using something like **map()** functions as per the code below but do not know
how to apply it. Any help or solutions will be appreciated

```
{this.state.contestantResult.map((contestant, i) => {
  //if (contestant.id == person.id) {

  if (contestant.id) {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <div>{contestant.voteCount}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
})}
```

**Below is my coding efforts so far**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Contestant extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div key={this.props.data.id}>
          <div style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}>
            <b>Id:</b>
            {this.props.data.id}
            <br />
            <b>Name:</b> {this.props.data.name}
            <br />
            <b style={{ color: "red" }}>Vote Count: {this.props.resultVotes}</b>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class VoteResult extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "contestant 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "contestant 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "contestant 3" }
      ],

      contestantResult: [
        { id: 1, voteCount: "500 Votes" },
        { id: 2, voteCount: "200 Votes" },
        { id: 3, voteCount: "320 votes" }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Electoral College Voting......</h1>

        {this.state.data.map(person => {
          return (
            <Contestant
              key={person.id}
              data={person}
              resultVotes={this.state.contestantResult[0].voteCount}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to take the first object in the `contestantResult` array for every iteration in the loop. You could instead use `find` to find the result of the correct contestant.

```
{this.state.data.map(person => {
  const result = this.state.contestantResult.find(res => res.id === person.id);

  return (
    <Contestant
      key={person.id}
      data={person}
      resultVotes={result.voteCount}
    />
  );
})}
```

```js
class VoteResult extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "contestant 1" },
      { id: 2, name: "contestant 2" },
      { id: 3, name: "contestant 3" }
    ],

    contestantResult: [
      { id: 1, voteCount: "500 Votes" },
      { id: 2, voteCount: "200 Votes" },
      { id: 3, voteCount: "320 votes" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { data, contestantResult } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Electoral College Voting......</h1>
        {data.map(person => {
          const result = contestantResult.find(res => res.id === person.id);
          
          return (
            <Contestant
              key={person.id}
              data={person}
              resultVotes={result.voteCount}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Contestant extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.props.data.id}>
        <div style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}>
          <b>Id:</b>
          {this.props.data.id}
          <br />
          <b>Name:</b> {this.props.data.name}
          <br />
          <b style={{ color: "red" }}>Vote Count: {this.props.resultVotes}</b>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<VoteResult />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```